# mvn install: Failure executing javac, but could not parse error

Tags: maven

It's the first time I try using mavan and I got the following error when I issued "mvn install" (running on vista):

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
C:\Users\Kaze Kun\.m2\respository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.2.1.GA\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar.  error in opening zip file
```

I googled and found some threads about needing to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.  However, this seems not the case for me since I've already set my JAVA_HOME variable at C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_24.  Just wondering what can be the cause of the problem?

Below is the more detail capture of the error messages from maven:

```
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MS932, i.e. bu
ild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA\examples\oreilly-w
orkbook\ex03_1\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
エラー:C:\Users\Kaze Kun\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.2.1.
GA\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar の読み込みエラーです。error in opening zip file
エラー 1 個

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:22.828s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 09 11:11:17 CST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project workbook-ex03_1: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] エラー:C:\Users\Kaze Kun\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxr
s\2.2.1.GA\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar の読み込みエラーです。error in opening zi
p file
[ERROR] エラー 1 個
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
C:\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA\examples\oreilly-workbook\ex03_1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that the `resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar` is corrupt.

You should try deleting this file

```
C:\Users\Kaze Kun\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxr
s\2.2.1.GA\resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar
```

and retrying.